# Alfresco Context initialization failed: RenditionServiceException

Tags: alfresco

Alfresco won't start with `RenditionServiceException`.
My alfresco version is 201707 and my OS is CentOS 6.
This start happening after a manual reboot. I haven't change nothing in my configuration or data. 
This is my catalina.out:

```
ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
 org.alfresco.service.cmr.rendition.RenditionServiceException: 10190019 Unable to find rendering action root node.
    at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.checkRenderingActionRootNodeExists(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:239)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.findActionNode(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:194)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.findOrCreateActionNode(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:217)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.saveRenditionDefinition(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:164)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionServiceImpl.saveRenditionDefinition(RenditionServiceImpl.java:414)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$1.execute(ThumbnailRegistry.java:179)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$1.execute(ThumbnailRegistry.java:1)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:333)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.initThumbnailDefinitions(ThumbnailRegistry.java:165)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$RegistryLifecycle$1.doWork(ThumbnailRegistry.java:485)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$RegistryLifecycle.onBootstrap(ThumbnailRegistry.java:481)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.onApplicationEvent(ThumbnailRegistry.java:440)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.onApplicationEvent(ThumbnailRegistry.java:1)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1966)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Nov 19, 2018 4:54:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener
org.alfresco.service.cmr.rendition.RenditionServiceException: 10190019 Unable to find rendering action root node.
    at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.checkRenderingActionRootNodeExists(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:239)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.findActionNode(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:194)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.findOrCreateActionNode(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:217)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.saveRenditionDefinition(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:164)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionServiceImpl.saveRenditionDefinition(RenditionServiceImpl.java:414)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$1.execute(ThumbnailRegistry.java:179)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$1.execute(ThumbnailRegistry.java:1)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:333)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.initThumbnailDefinitions(ThumbnailRegistry.java:165)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$RegistryLifecycle$1.doWork(ThumbnailRegistry.java:485)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$RegistryLifecycle.onBootstrap(ThumbnailRegistry.java:481)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.onApplicationEvent(ThumbnailRegistry.java:440)
    at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.onApplicationEvent(ThumbnailRegistry.java:1)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1966)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of corruption obviously happened, have you or someone else tempered with Alfresco lately? I'd suggest trying to add this node manually in an effort to get your installation up. Hopefully, you have a backup somewhere.

https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository/blob/master/src/main/java/org/alfresco/repo/rendition/RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java