# Alfresco Context initialization failed: RenditionServiceException after backup restore

Tags: alfresco

Alfresco won't start with RenditionServiceException. Alfresco version is community 6.1.2.

I have followed the hot backup guidelines to backup Alfresco. Now I wanted to test something in Alfresco and restored the backup per guidelines to a new virtual server with same specs as the original.

But after all data is restored, files and Postgre database and I try to start Alfresco/Tomacat then this is thrown:

```
2020-08-24 14:44:49,443 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V4.2-metadata-query-indexes
2020-08-24 14:44:49,481 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V5.1-metadata-query-indexes
2020-08-24 14:44:49,481 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V5.2-remove-jbpm-tables-from-db
2020-08-24 14:44:50,602 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin] [main] Using database URL 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco' with user 'alfresco'.
2020-08-24 14:44:50,603 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin] [main] Connected to database PostgreSQL version 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
2020-08-24 14:45:01,979 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2020-08-24 14:45:02,142 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:06,215 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] [main] Registered template processor Repository Template Processor for extension ftl
2020-08-24 14:45:06,222 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] [main] Registered script processor Repository Script Processor for extension js
2020-08-24 14:45:11,597 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'ContentStore' subsystem, ID: [ContentStore, managed, unencrypted]
2020-08-24 14:45:11,741 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'ContentStore' subsystem, ID: [ContentStore, managed, unencrypted] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:11,925 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Connecting to database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco, UserName=alfresco, PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
2020-08-24 14:45:11,926 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Schema managed by database dialect org.alfresco.repo.domain.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.
2020-08-24 14:45:12,338 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Applied patches detected: 226
2020-08-24 14:45:12,637 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Checking and patching Alfresco tables took 298 ms
2020-08-24 14:45:12,678 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Activiti tables need to be checked for patches
2020-08-24 14:45:12,857 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Checking and patching Activiti tables took 179 ms
2020-08-24 14:45:13,078 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Checking that all patches have been applied took 221 ms
2020-08-24 14:45:13,079 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Updating the DB schema took 1149 ms
2020-08-24 14:45:13,081 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] No changes were made to the schema.
2020-08-24 14:45:17,270 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.tenant.MultiTAdminServiceImpl] [main] Alfresco Multi-Tenant startup - 13 enabled tenants, 1 disabled tenants
2020-08-24 14:45:17,271 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'thirdparty' subsystem, ID: [thirdparty, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:17,970 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.pdfrenderer.AlfrescoPdfRendererContentTransformerWorker] [main] Using remote Alfresco PDF Renderer: Alfresco PDF Renderer Version 1.1 [5b0e0b81dt] 2018-02-20 15:34:00 using Pdfium [e53460ff] 2018-02-19 18:34:00 CEST
2020-08-24 14:45:17,972 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'thirdparty' subsystem, ID: [thirdparty, default] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:17,972 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'OOoJodconverter' subsystem, ID: [OOoJodconverter, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:18,045 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'OOoJodconverter' subsystem, ID: [OOoJodconverter, default] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:18,049 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] [main] The root data directory ('dir.root') is: /opt/alfresco/alf_data
2020-08-24 14:45:18,089 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter] [main] Checking for patches to apply ...
2020-08-24 14:45:18,564 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter] [main] No patches were required.
2020-08-24 14:45:18,642 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] [main] Found 5 module package(s).
2020-08-24 14:45:18,765 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] [main] Starting module 'de.fme.alfresco.JavascriptConsole-repo' version 0.6.1604291213.
2020-08-24 14:45:18,890 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] [main] Starting module 'org.alfresco.extencion.bulkexport' version 0.0.6.
2020-08-24 14:45:18,969 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] [main] Starting module 'uploader-plus-repo' version 1.6.1801311724.
2020-08-24 14:45:19,044 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] [main] Starting module 'alfresco-share-services' version 6.1.0.
2020-08-24 14:45:19,119 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] [main] Starting module 'alfresco-trashcan-cleaner' version 2.3.
2020-08-24 14:45:19,202 WARN  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] [main] A previously-installed module 'alfresco-aos-module' (version 1.1.6) is not present in your distribution.
2020-08-24 14:45:19,241 WARN  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] [main] A previously-installed module 'org.alfresco.integrations.google.docs' (version 3.0.4) is not present in your distribution.
2020-08-24 14:45:19,281 WARN  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] [main] A previously-installed module 'com.atolcd.alfresco.acp-import-export-51X-repo' (version 1.0.1) is not present in your distribution.
2020-08-24 14:45:19,320 WARN  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] [main] A previously-installed module 'org.alfresco.extension.bulkexport' (version 0.0.7) is not present in your distribution.
2020-08-24 14:45:19,323 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'fileServers' subsystem, ID: [fileServers, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:20,060 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'fileServers' subsystem, ID: [fileServers, default] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:20,061 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:20,255 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:20,256 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound]
2020-08-24 14:45:20,903 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:20,904 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound]
2020-08-24 14:45:21,016 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:21,016 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:21,051 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:21,338 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:21,437 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:21,498 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:21,631 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:21,721 INFO  [org.alfresco.service.descriptor.DescriptorService] [main] Alfresco JVM - v11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3; maximum heap size 3641.000MB
2020-08-24 14:45:21,721 INFO  [org.alfresco.service.descriptor.DescriptorService] [main] Server Mode :UNKNOWN
2020-08-24 14:45:21,728 INFO  [org.alfresco.service.descriptor.DescriptorService] [main] Alfresco Content Services started (Community Multi-Tenant). Current version: 6.1.2 (r4fe1d0d0-b205) schema 13,001. Originally installed version: 5.1.0 (r122274-b3) schema 9,016.
2020-08-24 14:45:21,751 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'ActivitiesFeed' subsystem, ID: [ActivitiesFeed, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:22,311 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'ActivitiesFeed' subsystem, ID: [ActivitiesFeed, default] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:22,315 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:22,349 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default] complete
2020-08-24 14:45:32,491 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] [main] Context initialization failed
org.alfresco.service.cmr.rendition.RenditionServiceException: 07240018 Unable to find rendering action root node.
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.checkRenderingActionRootNodeExists(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:246)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.findActionNode(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:201)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.findOrCreateActionNode(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:224)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.saveRenditionDefinition(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:171)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionServiceImpl.saveRenditionDefinition(RenditionServiceImpl.java:428)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$1.execute(ThumbnailRegistry.java:246)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$1.execute(ThumbnailRegistry.java:1)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:319)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.initThumbnailDefinitionsTransaction(ThumbnailRegistry.java:232)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.initThumbnailDefinitions(ThumbnailRegistry.java:204)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$RegistryLifecycle$2.doWork(ThumbnailRegistry.java:592)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:623)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$RegistryLifecycle.onBootstrap(ThumbnailRegistry.java:588)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.onApplicationEvent(ThumbnailRegistry.java:533)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.onApplicationEvent(ThumbnailRegistry.java:1)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:221)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:186)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:206)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:355)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
2020-08-24 14:45:32,838 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:32,839 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:32,862 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:32,863 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:32,863 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound]
2020-08-24 14:45:32,863 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound]
2020-08-24 14:45:32,864 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'fileServers' subsystem, ID: [fileServers, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:32,981 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'fileServers' subsystem, ID: [fileServers, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,032 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'ActivitiesFeed' subsystem, ID: [ActivitiesFeed, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,034 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'ActivitiesFeed' subsystem, ID: [ActivitiesFeed, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,037 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'OOoJodconverter' subsystem, ID: [OOoJodconverter, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,037 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'OOoJodconverter' subsystem, ID: [OOoJodconverter, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,038 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'ContentStore' subsystem, ID: [ContentStore, managed, unencrypted]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,038 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'ContentStore' subsystem, ID: [ContentStore, managed, unencrypted]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,046 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,046 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,047 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,048 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,050 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,053 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,845 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'thirdparty' subsystem, ID: [thirdparty, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,846 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'thirdparty' subsystem, ID: [thirdparty, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,856 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,856 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,858 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopping 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
2020-08-24 14:45:33,858 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Stopped 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
```

This makes me think that the production server will not start if it ever is stopped. It has been over one  year since last reboot.

As you can see, the database connection works. And if I do not restore the database content, then the bootstrap works and I got an empty repository. So one could think the data is corrupted, but it works on the original server.

So, any suggestions?

I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381065/alfresco-context-initialization-failed-renditionserviceexception) as the closes match. But do not understand the answer and no solution provided.

Comment: On the machine still running, can you access the node browser? And if so, what is in data dictionary, and is the renditions folder node there?

Comment: @Gagravarr -- I found a node named rendering_actions and it had 7 children. Good to know about the dictionary thing. I asked the same question on Alfresco hub a couple of days ago and did get an answer now, which kind of solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Added following to alfresco-global.properties and Alfresco started up.

```
system.thumbnail.redeployStaticDefsOnStartup=false
```

Thank you to user kaynezhang on Alfresco Hub for this answer.